# Override image properties

Tags: javascript, html, css, vb.net, image

I have a usercontrol which includes an image. I am not able to modify image's styling property from my UI page.

```
  <td class="innerDiv">
       <div style="width: 100%;">
             <uc:ImgControl ID="imgC1" runat="server" />
       </div>
  </td>
```

I want the height and width to be different from whatever is currently loaded. Is there a way I can modify/override the width property of image in the above shown code?

I cannot do it in the UserControl page as the control has been used at other places as well.

Any pointers ?

Comment: jquery attr() can do this or you can change it using css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.innerDiv img {
  width: xx !important;
  haight: xx !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you may change css:

```
.innerDiv img {
  width: ...;
  haight: ...;
}
```

*If it is not the only place where we set it, then you may use `important` directive*

Or add in js something like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('innerDiv');

for (var i in elements) {
  elements[i].style.width = '...';
  elements[i].style.height = '...';
}
```